# How to export an jupyter interactive output within vsc as pdf

Tags: python, pdf, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using visual studio code and I am using the python extension to run jupyter notebooks. A "python interactive" window is opened within vsc and displays the jupyter Notebook. I am wondering how do easily export this as pdf?

It is possible to export an ipython notebook, from there I can create an pdf … but these very unhandy ….

Code:

## %%

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl 
import numpy as np
```

## %%

```
x = np.linspace(0,20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
#plt.show()
```

## %%

Screenshot:
[image: vscode jupyter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could log a suggestion on our github issues list:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new.

Otherwise we don't currently support exporting to PDF. Just ipynb.

Comment: Hi Chiodo,
thx, i just posted a new issue.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4624